# Replace the content of specific cells in a tsv file with the edited content of other cells

Tags: text-processing

I have a tsv file like this:

```
col1            col2           
etc              ok             
something        NULL                
category1        ok           
randomtext       NULL
```

I need to replace "NULL" with the content of the cell on the left plus a number 2. Something like: if content of cell matches the string "NULL", replace it with the content of the cell on its left and add a number 2:

```
col1            col2      
etc              ok             
something        something2                
category1        ok           
randomtext       randomtext2
```

Thanks

Comment: It replaces NULL with only the first word of the left cell. How can it be tweaked to include all the content of the cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS="\t" } { if ($2=="NULL"){ $2=$1"2" } print }' file
```

If field `$2` is `NULL`, assign field `$1` and `"2"` to field `$2`. Then print the line.

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\([^[:blank:]]*\)\([[:blank:]]*\)NULL\([[:blank:]]*\)/\1\2\12\3/' file
```

Capture the first column, the following space and the (possible) space after column 2 in three groups and replace with group one, two, one + "2" and three.

Comment: Worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) is

```
mlr --tsv put -S 'if ($col2 == "NULL") {$col2 = $col1."2"}' input.tsv
```

Answer (score 2):

With `csvsql` from the Python-based `csvkit`:

```
csvsql -t --query '
  SELECT col1, CASE WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN col1||"2" ELSE col2 END AS col2 FROM stdin
' < file.tsv | csvformat -T
col1    col2
etc ok
something   something2
category1   ok
randomtext  randomtext2
```

Comment: Wow, and here I thought I’d seen about everything when it came to command line text processing.  Very nice, will have to look into csvsql.

Comment: @Wildcard tbh it's overkill for the stated application - I just wanted to see if I could do it ;) Unlike the straight "text processing" approaches it should be able to handle cases where the fields contain quoted embedded separators - as does the nice [mlr solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/542565/65304) (probably more efficient than mine)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed it is trivial:

```
$ sed -E 's/^([^\t]+)\tNULL(\t|$)/\1\t\12\2/' file
```

Comment: It's due to a typo, we need the uppercase E. Thanks for catching.